# Avoid page refresh after ImageClickEventHandler fire

Tags: c#, asp.net, imagebutton

I have a ImageButton which will show Calendar after it is clicked. I want to stop page refresh when the ImageButton is clicked, but I've tried a couple of ways and none of them work. Is it possible to avoid page refresh and just show the calendar after the Image Button is clicked?

Here is my c# code

```
TableRow first = new TableRow();
TableCell four = new TableCell();
ImageButton btnDateToggle = new ImageButton();
btnDateToggle.ID = $"btnDateToggle_{j}";
btnDateToggle.ImageUrl = "images/icon2.gif";
btnDateToggle.Click += new ImageClickEventHandler(BtnDateToggle_Click);
Calendar dateddl = new Calendar();
dateddl.ID = $"dateddl_{j}"
dateddl.Width = 250;
dateddl.Visible = false;
dateddl.SelectionChanged += new EventHandler(Dateddl_SelectionChanged);
four.Controls.Add(btnDateToggle);
four.Controls.Add(dateddl);
first.Cells.Add(four);
tasksTable.Rows.Add(first);
ChildPane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(tasksTable);
ChildAccordion.Panes.Add(ChildPane);
ParentPane.ContentContainer.Controls.Add(ChildAccordion);
MasterAccordion.Panes.Add(ParentPane);
MyContent.Controls.Add(MasterAccordion);
```

ChildPane and ParentPane are AccordionPane Object. ChildAccordion is an Accordion Object

```
protected void BtnDateToggle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string btnDateToggleID = ((Control)sender).ID;
    string index = btnDateToggleID.Substring(btnDateToggleID.IndexOf('_') + 1);
    Calendar dateddl = (Calendar)FindControlRecursive(Page, $"dateddl_{index}");
    dateddl.Visible = !dateddl.Visible;
}
protected void Dateddl_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Calendar dateddl = (Calendar)sender;
    string dateddlID = dateddl.ID;
    string index = dateddlID.Substring(dateddlID.IndexOf('_') + 1);
    TextBox textBox = (TextBox)FindControlRecursive(Page, $"txtDate_{index}");
    dateddl.Visible = false;
    textBox.Text = dateddl.SelectedDate.ToShortDateString();//.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy");
}
```

Here is my client side code (.aspx)

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:Panel ID="MyContent" runat="server">  
        <ajaxToolkit:Accordion  ID="MasterAccordion" runat="server"> </ajaxToolkit:Accordion>
    </asp:Panel>  
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, you can use an `<asp:UpdatePanel>` to avoid page refresh. To learn more about this you can visit https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.ui.updatepanel?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Could you add client side codes as well?

Comment: @LucSil but these are added in aspx.cs file, my aspx file only has <asp:Content><div></div></asp:Content> in it.

Comment: @SelimYıldız Do you mean .aspx file?

Comment: Do you add `btnDateToggle` into `MyContent` panel, right?

Comment: @SelimYıldız Yes, I've updated the code at the end of the c# code